# WebScraper with java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using java for my project because it's what I was taught in university.
I hope you guys can help me. After a lot of search and use of some tools, I'm wondering what's the best tool to use. Listed below are the ones I have searched for more information on:
WebDriver with PhantomJS(looking for someone to help me with this)
Jsoup(can't read JavaScript)
Nutch(I haven't used it yet)

Jsoup is no longer an alternative. I was getting the information from most pages, but some were loaded by JS with ajax requests, so I moved to WebDriver with PhantomJS. The main problem is I don't really know how to use it properly. When I click the NEXT button, I have to wait for the JS to load the new page.

The main code just for testing:

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    ArrayList<String> nmNavio = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> prevChegada = new ArrayList<String>();
    WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.embraportonline.com.br/Navios/Escala");
    do{
        int tabSize = 0;


        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#wrapper > div > div.wrapper.wrapper-content > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.ibox-content > div.table-responsive > table > tbody.text-center"));
        List<WebElement> elements = element.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 
        tabSize = elements.size();

        for(int a = 1; a<tabSize+1;a++)
        {
            nmNavio.add(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#wrapper > div > div.wrapper.wrapper-content > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.ibox-content > div.table-responsive > table > tbody.text-center > tr:nth-child("+a+") > td:nth-child(1) > text")).getText());
            prevChegada.add(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#wrapper > div > div.wrapper.wrapper-content > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.ibox-content > div.table-responsive > table > tbody.text-center > tr:nth-child("+a+") > td:nth-child(8) > text")).getText());
        }
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ornext")).click();

    }while(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ornext")).isDisplayed());
    for(int a = 0; a<nmNavio.size();a++)
    {
        System.out.println(nmNavio.get(a));
        System.out.println(prevChegada.get(a));
    }
    driver.quit();
}
```

How can I create a listener that fires when the new content is displayed and THEN execute some code.

Comment: I could do it by checking if there is 0 connections, there is some method in webdriver to check it?